# Delphi: PostThreadMessage & PeekMessage not working

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2009

When my main application (Delphi 2009) terminates, I want it to signal my threads (timers, TDataModules with ADO Connections, SMTP etc) to dispose gracefully.

In my main application, I have the following:

```
try
      PostThreadMessage(bpvccMAILER.ThreadID, WM_SYSTEM_CLOSE, self.Handle, 0);
      returnMessage := (SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)); //Returns 'The operation completed successfully'
    while TRUE do
            begin
                sleep(1000);
                if not (Assigned(bpvccMAILER)) then
                begin
                    bpvccACTIVITY_LOGGER.Write('SHUTDOWN','TBPVCommunicatorGUI.FormClose - All Threads have shut down');
                    break;
                end;
                locWaited := locWaited  + 10;
            end;  
        except
        end;
    finally
        FreeAndNil(bpvccACTIVITY_LOGGER);
        FreeAndNil(bpvccMAILER);
    end;
```

Thread class:

```
TBPVMailer = class(TThread)
    protected
        SMTP       : TIdSMTP;
        interval   : Integer;
        fMain      : Integer;
        fMainIsSvc : Boolean;
        fTerminated: Boolean;
        function SendEmail(AEmail: TEmailObj) : TBPVEmailSendResult;
        function doSleep : Boolean;
        procedure Write(AStatus, AMessage : String);
        procedure FlushQueue();
        procedure HandleMessage(var Message : TMessage); message WM_SYSTEM_CLOSE;
    public
        constructor Create(AServer : String; APort : Integer; AUser, APass : String; AInterval : Integer; StartSuspended : Boolean); overload;
        procedure   Execute; override;
        procedure QueueEmail(AEmail: TEmailObj; EmailType : TBPVEmailType; AssociatedID : String);
        destructor Destroy; override;
end;

procedure TBPVMailer.HandleMessage(var Message: TMessage);
var
msg : tagMSG;
begin
  PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
    fMain := Message.WParam;
    fMainIsSvc := Message.LParam = 1;
    fTerminated := TRUE;
end;
```

Problem is, Assigned(bpvccMAILER) always returns true even after calling PostThreadMessage. Also, bpvccMAILER.fTerminated is always FALSE, which means the TBPVMailer.HandleMessage is never executed because that is were the value is set to TRUE. What am I doing wrong, it appears that my threads arent receiving the messages?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious explanation is that you don't have a message pump in your thread. You post the message, but the thread does not pump its queue.

The code is needlessly complex though. There seems to be no need for messages at all. Call the `Terminate` method of the thread and then use its `WaitFor` method to wait until it stops. Or even simpler, just call `Free` on the thread.

Your code does contain a number of oddities:

- Why do you call `PeekMessage`? That serves no purpose that I can discern.
- Waiting with `Sleep` should be avoided. You can almost always use dedicated wait functions.
- It's odd the you wait until `bpvccMAILER` is `nil`, but then use `FreeAndNil(bpvccMAILER)`.
- You must only call `GetLastError` when it is well-defined. Typically that is only when the preceeded API call has failed. And failure is indicated by the value returned by the API call.

Comment: **DO NOT** call `Free()` on a `TThread` that is still running. Doing so causes problems, and has for a LONG time. **ALWAYS** fully terminate a `TThread` before then freeing it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Are you going to justify that with detail? You could start by reading the source code for `TThread.Destroy` and observing the presence of `Terminate` followed by `WaitFor`. Unless you have something specific to offer, this is **FUD**.

Comment: I am not going to waste my time providing details here. There are plenty of past discussions in the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero forums that describe in detail the kind of problems that happen with freeing a running `TThread` object. The fact that the destructor tries to call `WaitFor()` (and sometimes fails to do so) is part of the problem. Do your own research. It **CAN** and **DOES** cause problems. So DO NOT do it.

Comment: @Remy Without details this smells like FUD. Your cure is to call Terminate, then WaitFor and then Free? How does that differ from calling Free? It is disappointing that you cannot bring yourself to explain this. You may very well be right but I've never been very swayed by *proof by the use of bold type*.

Comment: Yes, manually calling `Terminate()` and `WaitFor()` before calling `Free()` is 1) preferred and 2) safer than letting the `TThread` destructor call `WaitFor()` internally. Do some research before riding this off as FUD. I am not saying this lightly. There ARE problems with it.

Comment: @Remy So provide details instead of shouting. Bold face and upper case does not strengthen your case. Surely this is something that I should know. So give me the pointers.

Comment: Like I said, do your own searches in the forum archives. There are plenty of examples available. I don't have time to track things down for you. You posted an answer, you should have done your research first.

Comment: @remy That's really weak. Searching in the forums is a nightmare. You routinely help here on SO. And for some reason you refuse to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Sleep loop in the main thread is not OK since it blocks processing messages.

Just call the PostThreadMessage and return, without any Sleep loop afterwards.

If you need to wait until bpvccMAILER finishes, add code that on completion send a PostMessage to your main thread. So, the main thread will handle this message and will be aware that the auxiliary thread has finished. It may not be easy to change your application this way straight from the start, but little by little you will be designing applications in such a way that always does correct thread handling.

Besides that, if you use PostThreadMessage, then your Thread.Execute loop must have MsgWaitForMultipleObjects.

Here is an example on how the Thread.Execute loop have to be:

```
<skipped>
repeat
  <skipped>
  R := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(EventCount, EventArray, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
  <skipped>
  if R = WAIT_OBJECT_0 + EventCount then
  begin
    while PeekMessage(M, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
    begin
      if M.Message = WM_QUIT then
        Break;
      TranslateMessage(M);
      DispatchMessage(M);
    end;
    if M.Message = WM_QUIT then
      Break;
  end;
  <skipped>
until Terminated;
<skipped>
```

If your application will eventually need to exit while the tread is running (assume your thread object is in T variable), do the following:

```
T.Terminate;
SetEvent([one of the event of the EventArray]); // we should call it AFTER terminate for the Terminated property would already be True when the tread exits from MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
T.WaitFor; 
T.Free; // "Free" calls "WaitFor" anyway, but Remy Lebeau suggests to explicitly call "WaitFor" before "Free".
T := nil;
```